# Write array to txt file

Tags: php

I have a form on a website that once completed holds the values in an array. I wish to put the contents of the array into a txt file, each submission on a new line, values seperated by '-':

```
info-info-info-info
info-info-info-info
```

I've tried using:

```
foreach ($clean as $info) {
    $file = fopen("userinfo.txt", "w");
    fwrite($file, $info);
    fclose($file);
}
```

This only put the last part of the array in the text file and overwrites the file on each submission.

Using:

```
$results = var_export($clean, true); 
file_put_contents('userinfo.txt', $results);
```

writes all the info to the file correctly but stores as a var dump, and overwrites on each submission. I don't know how to format it to achieve what I need. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you handle values containing `-` themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically writing a CSV (comma-separated values) file. PHP has the right function to do the job builtin: [`fputcsv`](http://php.net/fputcsv) (As an added bonus it will also properly handle escaping of values containing the separator themselves);

```
if($h = fopen('./path/to/file', 'a')) {
  fputcsv($h, $clean, '-');
  fclose($h);
}
```

Use [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/fgetcsv) to retrieve the data at a later point.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here but doesn't fputcsv expect the 2nd argument to be an array? So you don't need that foreach loop at all.

Comment: @Tom: yeah, you are right. I thought you were dealing with multi-dimensional arrays

Comment: I don't really want to ask a new question for this but how would I include in the form to check if a value is already in the file? If it was a MySQL db I'd be ok but I suck at txt file. When checking a field I open the file and check for existing value>?

Comment: @Tom: then why don't you use a DB? It sounds like you actually want to use a database. For a CSV file to check if a value already exists, you'd have to re-read the complete file and then search for the value.

Comment: Its ok I figured it out now, and it's working. Well, if it was up to me I'd be using a db! But it's not!

Comment: @Tom: Have you (or the person in charge) considered using a standalone database, such as SQLite?

Answer (score 2):

```
$info = implode("\n",$clean);
file_put_contents("userinfo.txt", $info);
```

PS: Don't use fopen inside of loop but outside and later just fwrite inside.
fclose goes after loop.

Edit: I misunderstood a bit
it should be

```
$info = implode("-",$clean);
file_put_contents("userinfo.txt", "\n".$info,FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change (from write only mode to append mode)

```
$file = fopen("userinfo.txt", "w");
```

To

```
$file = fopen("userinfo.txt", "a");
```

Comment: So if I use   fwrite($file, $info.'-'); it will seperate the values, how do I put each submission on a new line?

Comment: Try `fwrite($file, $info."-"."\n");`

Comment: That will put each record on a new line. It need to have the new line after the last record, and also not have the "-" after the last record. Any ideas?